# recursive strstr function in c

Tags: c, string, recursion, strstr

I wrote my recursive strstr but the problem is that if I have this code:

```
char *str = "Yesterday all my troubles seemed so far away";
char *subStr[6] = { "Yes", "all", "my", "see", "far", "day" };
char *res;
int i;
printf("%s\n", str);
res = str;
for (i = 0; i<6; i++)
{
    printf("%s\n", subStr[i]);
    res = recursiveStrStr(res, subStr[i]);
    if (res == 0)
    {
        printf("The specified text is not found.\n");
        break;
    }
    else
        printf("The found text: %s\n", res);
}
```

My strstr return str very well till it gets to i=5
so the substr is "day" and str that left is "far away" and it should return 0 - that means text not found but it returns str dont understand why ?

my strstr code (should be recursive):

```
int recursiveStrStr(char * str, char *substr)
{

    if (str == NULL  )
        return 0;
    else if (strncmp(str, substr, strlen(substr)) == 0)
        return str;
    else 
        return(recursiveStrStr(str+1, substr));

}
```

Comment: You are using `return str` for a function that is supposed to return an `int`. Is that on purpose?

Comment: What is strstr supposed to return?  The number of matches in the string?

Comment: it suppost to return the ddress of str so the main function prints str from this adress (from substr and till the end).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it should be `(*str == NULL)` ?

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible to write a recursive strstr without calling any other functions but strstr itself:

```
char *RecStrStr(const char *haystack, const char *needle)
{
    assert(haystack);
    assert(needle);

    if(*needle == 0)
        return (char *)haystack;

    if(*haystack == 0)
        return NULL;

    if(*haystack == *needle &&
        RecStrStr(haystack + 1, needle + 1) == haystack + 1)
        return (char *)haystack;

    return RecStrStr(haystack + 1, needle);
}
```

Basically, there are two types of recursive calls:

1. Needle and haystack current chars match, in which case you would advance both pointers to compare the next chars.
2. The current char of needle does not match the current char of haystack, in which case you would only advance the position of haystack.

If the null termination was reached, it is because needle is not a substring of haystack, and NULL is returned.

If the null termination of needle was reached, it is because haystack and needle matched consecutively, and a pointer to the current haystack position is returned.

Why? This is where things get a bit more complicated - in order to not return a positive answer when needle is a non-consecutive substring of haystack, we need to make sure that the return value of the next match is the pointer following the current following (this is the second condition in the third if).

If needle is indeed a substring of haystack, the return value will be the pointer in which the matching began, as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You need another clause for returning "not found".

```
if ( *str == '\0' )
   return NULL;
```

Without that, you keep in incrementing `str` until you access out of bounds memory.

Also, I would change the return type of the function to `char*`.

```
char* recursiveStrStr(char * str, char *substr)
{
   if (str == NULL  )
      return NULL;

   if ( *str == '\0' )
      return NULL;

   if (strncmp(str, substr, strlen(substr)) == 0)
      return str;

   return(recursiveStrStr(str+1, substr));
}
```

Comment: I cant, I have to make it int recursive strstr, and in the main it matters only if it 0 or not, so is there really big diffrents between return 0 or return NULL?

Comment: @TaniaGalan, the return type matters a lot. If size of `char*` is bigger than `sizeof(int)`, you will end up returning a truncated value, which will cause havoc in the function that uses the returned value, a truncated `int,` as a `char*`.